# in for loop select statement retrieve only last column value in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

```
     Dim AR As New DD With {.DAT = {DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy"), DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy")}}
    Dim sResult As String = String.Join(" , ", AR.DAT)
    MessageBox.Show(sResult)

    For index As Integer = 0 To AR.DAT.Length - 1
        TextBox1.Text = AR.DAT(index)

        Dim cMD As New SqlCommand("select [" & TextBox1.Text & "] from Attendance ", con)
        Dim aD As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dtR As New DataTable
        aD.SelectCommand = cMD
        aD.Fill(dtR)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dtR
        con.Close()

    Next
```

This code return only last column value... how should i retrieve all value in array to datagridview

Comment: is there values for your query ?

Comment: am learning dot net ... THAT Y I ASK...

Comment: sure you are free to ask,but make sure you do some research on the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 For index As Integer = 0 To AR.DAT.Length - 1
        TextBox1.Text = AR.DAT(index)
```

This loops through them all, nut it's too fast to see. You want to see all values in `testxbox`:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + AR.DAT(index)
```

Better way to use listbox

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(index)
```